# MS Project office addin

Tags: office-js, office-addins, ms-project, project-web-addins

I am trying to create a MS project addin, Following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/project-quickstart), I created a sample addin for Project using yeoman and [import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins) the addin, but addin is stuck at "Please sideload your add-in to see app body". It seems Office does not hit the "Ready" state and thus never calling the onReady event/function.

The node version: 14.17.0.
OS: Win 10
Project Desktop Client version: 2105 (build 14026.20270)
Office.js version: 1.1
Running the app in dev mode with a network share to load the addin.

This is what it looks like in Project. [Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8spbW.png)

Steps i followed:

- install yeoman and generate addin for project
- build and start the app using npm run dev-server
- shared a directory and place the manifest xml in it
- started project, enabled my shared folder catalog
- opened a project and loaded the addin

Is MS Project supported by the addin framework? Has anyone tried it with the new Project?
I see no errors in console.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your add-in is running in MS Project correctly. You just need to change task pane web page and remove the statement to sideload the add-in. See [Task pane add-ins for Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/project/project-add-ins) for more information.

Comment: I thought the Office API need to be "Ready" before we can run any api's, is that not the case?

Comment: what code did you put into the `onReady` event handler to make sure the add-in works correctly? and how do you expect it should be working?

Comment: Followed the example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/project-quickstart)